Connect Vertica DB in SpringBoot App with multiple datasource
I'm not able to run the application in test environment due to missing driver.
This is the error I'm getting: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.vertica.jdbc.Driver
Being a multi-module project these are the dependencies in parent pom
<dependencies>

            <!-- spring cloud -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.0</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud-dependencies.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud-stream.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>

            <!-- spring boot -->

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-boot-dependencies.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
            </dependency>

            <!-- swagger -->

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
                <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
                <version>${springdoc.version}</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-config-server</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud-config-server.version}</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-deploy-plugin.version}</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.json</groupId>
                <artifactId>json</artifactId>
                <version>${json.version}</version>
            </dependency>


            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId>
                <version>${org.mapstruct.version}</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-config-client</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud-config-client.version}</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
                <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
                <version>${google-guava.version}</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
                <artifactId>itextpdf</artifactId>
                <version>5.5.13.3</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.lowagie</groupId>
                <artifactId>itext</artifactId>
                <version>4.2.2</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
                <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
                <scope>runtime</scope>
            </dependency>

        </dependencies>



This is the pom from the module where vertica connection has to be created
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>core</artifactId>
        <groupId>it.xx.xx.xx</groupId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>xxxxx-service</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
        <spring-cloud-config-client.version>3.1.1</spring-cloud-config-client.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>

        <!-- spring cloud -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-config-client</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-cloud-config-client.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-stream-kafka</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-openfeign</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <!-- spring boot -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-autoconfigure</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <!-- kafka -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>kafka-streams</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- misc -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20231013</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.16.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.16.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
            <version>2.13.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-s3</artifactId>
            <version>1.12.239</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vladmihalcea</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-types-52</artifactId>
            <version>2.16.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- swagger -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.swagger.core.v3</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.13</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.swagger.core.v3</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.13</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-data-rest</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.6</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-sleuth</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
            <version>1.11</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <!-- testing -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
                    <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
                    <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.13.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.11.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>software.amazon.msk</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-msk-iam-auth</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.12.322</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
            <artifactId>itextpdf</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Vertica -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vertica.jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>vertica-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>24.1.0-0</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6.4</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <!-- for testing porpoises -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.22.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <argLine>--add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED</argLine>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>


This is my property file:
## Vertica DB configuration properties
spring.vertica-datasource.url=jdbc:vertica://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:5433/dbname
spring.vertica-datasource.username=XXXX
spring.vertica-datasource.password=XXXXXX
spring.vertica-datasource.driver-class-name=com.vertica.jdbc.Driver
spring.vertica-datasource.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect

And this is the configuration class
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        basePackages = "it.xx.xx.xx.repo.vertica",
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "verticaEntityManagerFactory",
        transactionManagerRef = "verticaTransactionManager")
public class VerticaDataSourceConfig {

    @Value("${spring.vertica-datasource.hibernate.dialect}")
    private String dialect;

    @Bean(name="verticaDBProperties")
    @ConfigurationProperties("spring.vertica-datasource")
    public DataSourceProperties dataSourceProperties() {
        return new DataSourceProperties();
    }

    @Bean(name="verticaDBDatasource")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.vertica-datasource")
    public DataSource datasource(@Qualifier("verticaDBProperties") DataSourceProperties properties){
        return properties.initializeDataSourceBuilder().build();
    }

    @Bean(name="verticaEntityManagerFactoryBuilder")
    public EntityManagerFactoryBuilder entityManagerFactoryBuilder() {
        return new EntityManagerFactoryBuilder(new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter(), new HashMap<>(), null);
    }

    @Bean(name="verticaEntityManagerFactory")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean
            (@Qualifier("verticaEntityManagerFactoryBuilder") EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder, @Qualifier("verticaDBDatasource") DataSource dataSource){

        Map<String, String> properties = new HashMap<>();
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect", dialect);

        return builder.dataSource(dataSource)
                .packages("it.xx.xx.xx.entity.db.vertica")
                .persistenceUnit("verticaDB")
                .properties(properties)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean(name = "verticaTransactionManager")
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(
            @Qualifier("verticaEntityManagerFactory") EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {

        return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory);
    }
    

}


The problem is that the error appears only in test environment, locally I'm using a dockerized vertica instance and no problem appears
We're using AWS for deployment and building the app I can see that the dependency is downloaded from Maven central, still when pod is created (we use kubernetes) the ClassNotFoundException is thrown at startup.
I also tried loading the driver using the jar file, through ResourceLoader with same result, working locally but failing in test environment
I'm running out of ideas, please any help would be greatly appreciated.

Show your dependencies.

Thank you for reply, post updated with dependencies, let me know if I need to provide something else.

At a first look you are trying very hard to work around the provided dependency management of SPring Boot. Which Spring Boot version are you actually using?

I'm using Spring Boot version 2.6.4. Could you please clarify what you mean by 'trying very hard to work around the provided dependency management of Spring Boot'? I genuinely want to understand if there's a more optimal approach I should be considering. No offense taken; I appreciate your input and am here to learn and improve.

You are defining a lot of dependencies which are already in the spring-boot-starter-* dependencies, the spring-boot-dependencies is in the wrong place and you are also including incompatible dependencies.  spring-boot-starter-web already includes spring-boot-starter-tomcat, spring-jdbc isn't needed and is incompatible. spring-boot-autoconfigure is already part of all the other starters and not optional at all. Mixing versions of Apache POI and Jacksons dependencies. spring-cloud-config-client version managed outside of spring cloud dependencies.

Thanks for the insights. Truly appreciate your detailed feedback and I'll review the dependencies. Could the dependency issues also be why the Vertica driver works locally but fails in the test environment?

The spring-jdbc one is at least problematic as that isn't for Spring Boot 2.6.x (which isn't supported anymore just so you know). If the jar is in your end jar it should be found, so unless you are copying the wrong jar or doing some other processing with it it might be removed. Finally why is there the jaxb2-maven-plugin as a dependency? A plugin as a dependency doesn't really make sense.

I removed the spring-jdbc and now everything's working correctly, thank you for your patience and guidance on everything, yet I don't understand why the dependency were not causing problem when running on my machine.

In the end the dependency causing the issue were the spring-jdbc as indicated by @M. Deinum.
with that one removed everything's loading properly.
Thanks to @M. Deinum for suggestions on how to better manage spring boot dependendencies.

Have you told the configuration that the Vertica driver is here?
/opt/vertica/lib/vertica-jdbc-xx.x.x-x.jar

(Where x stands for a digit - and the format indicates the version of the driver) ...

In the end the main issue was the spring-jdbc dependency. I removed it and everything started working correctly, without using the manual loading from jar
